# why my app.component.html file is not working?

Tags: angular

whenever i run my program it gives me a blank screen. except the title name . below is the source code of my project. i also tried it by writing html code in app.component.html file but still it is displaying blank screen.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

**nav-bar.component.html**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <a routerLink="/home">home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a routerLink="/about">about</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

**nav-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>WatchMe</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"integrity="sha384Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { BookTicketComponent } from './components/book-ticket/book-ticket.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/sign/signup/signup.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'home',
    component:HomeComponent

  },
  {
    path:'about',
    component:AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path:'book_ticket',
    component:BookTicketComponent
  },
  {
    path:'sign_signup',
    component:SignupComponent
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    component:AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path:'navbar',
    component:NavBarComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule ,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { BookTicketComponent } from './components/book-ticket/book-ticket.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/sign/signup/signup.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    BookTicketComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,

    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please post your regular app.module.ts. Did you remember to include AppRoutingModule in your imports?

Comment: plz check it now

Comment: Any console errrors?

Comment: no console error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the base href from your header tags

**index.html**

```html
<head>
  <base href="/" /> // this has to be there for angular routing to work correctly
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>WatchMe</title>
</head>
```

You are also not specifying a default route

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  // specify your default route here
  // this means when it lands on / it will go to the home page
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path:'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path:'book_ticket',
    component: BookTicketComponent
  },
  {
    path:'sign_signup',
    component: SignupComponent
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path:'navbar',
    component: NavBarComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: If you change the default route to be 'about' do you get the same get error?

Comment: 'cannot Get' error has been resolved but i am still getting blank screen

Comment: Do you have any html written in your AboutComponent?

Comment: Add this to the top of your `<head></head>` in your index.html `<base href="/" />` does this solve the issue?

Comment: please check my app.module.ts and app.routing.module.ts again , i might be missing something there

Comment: Did you put the `<base href="/" />` in your header tags?